# How to define photo from camera is rotated

Tags: camera, rotation, metadata, jpeg, photo

Is there any standard meta-data field in JPEG or other formats that defines photo is made rotated +-90° (i mean camera was rotated).

Some graphic viewers displays this photos correctly. So, i guess they read some image format headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html) is some information on the subject.